# Benefits of using image_tag over <img>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, assets

Are there benefits of using `image_tag` instead of `<img src="">` in view files? If so, what are they?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For images that are part of your application, use of `image_tag` or `asset_path` to access your image from the asset pipeline is much preferred. This will ensure that the correct file name (including MD5 hash code) is included in the path to the image. This will allow your app to take advantage of asset pipeline features such as compression, cache control etc. The asset pipeline-based helpers will also ensure that the image exists in development mode by raising an exception.

Here's a link to the Rails documentation on the asset pipeline: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

The asset pipeline seems a little daunting at first, but it leads to vastly superior performance and maintainability in production deployments of your application.